# Lasso model by glmnet package in small sample size

Tags: r, cross-validation, lasso, caret, glmnet

I want to create a lasso model, but I can't have a test set because I have a small sample size. So, I want to use cross-validation to evaluate the model.
I have seen that functions like `cv.glmnet` and caret are used to make the lasso model. Now I want to know if it is possible to get the confusion matrix from `cv.glmnet` or should I use `caret` instead of `cv.glmnet?` Or will `cv.glmnet` be used as inner CV for picking lambda and `caret` for outer CV? Knowing this question is important for me to make sure if I should use `cv.glmnet` or not.